# Accessibility (WCAG 2.0) do we NEED labels in table cells

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I'm implementing a system following version 2.0 of the WCAG guidelines.

I have tabular data  in the form of an editable grid this is rendered using a table. I have given the table column headings and used the scope attribute on the table cells.

Going by the WAVE tool, evey form control should have a matching label, but in the context of tabular data this seems to be a bit silly.

Does anyone know of any guidance on this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H65.html suggests maybe can use title instead of label in some cases

Comment: http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/20081211/#content-structure-separation-programmatic also mentions labels in H44 and data tables in H63 but both are "sufficient"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in the comments: yes, a `title` attribute should be enough. In H65 (and maybe others) under Resources there is a link to a (very!) useful article about forms and WCAG 2 called [Accessible Forms using WCAG 2.0](http://www.usability.com.au/resources/wcag2/), where they provide some examples -- and tests them in some screen readers. I think the section "Form controls in data tables" in that article should be enough "proof" that the `title` attribute is enough.